# How do we set the the RAM and disk space for a docker container?

Tags: docker, virtual-machine, docker-machine

Following are the details of the docker containers and images that I have.

```
Animeshs-MacBook-Pro:docker_tests animesh$ docker-machine ls
NAME          ACTIVE   URL          STATE     URL                         SWARM   DOCKER    ERRORS
celery-test   *        virtualbox   Running   tcp://192.168.99.100:2376           v1.9.1    
hello-world   -        virtualbox   Stopped                                       Unknown   

Animeshs-MacBook-Pro:docker_tests animesh$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS                      PORTS               NAMES
33f0eca77b4c        celery-image1       "/bin/bash"         2 hours ago         Exited (0) 25 minutes ago                       current_image
a4607f34b309        ubuntu:latest       "/bin/bash"         4 hours ago         Exited (0) 3 hours ago                          celery_app

Animeshs-MacBook-Pro:docker_tests animesh$ docker-machine ssh celery-test
Boot2Docker version 1.9.1, build master : cef800b - Fri Nov 20 19:33:59 UTC 2015
Docker version 1.9.1, build a34a1d5

docker@celery-test:~$ df -h
Filesystem                Size      Used Available Use% Mounted on
tmpfs                   896.6M    889.6M      7.0M  99% /
tmpfs                   498.1M         0    498.1M   0% /dev/shm
cgroup                  498.1M         0    498.1M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none                    464.8G     44.0G    420.8G   9% /Users
tmpfs                   896.6M    889.6M      7.0M  99% /mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/aufs

docker@celery-test:~$ exit

Animeshs-MacBook-Pro:docker_tests animesh$ docker start current_image
current_image

Animeshs-MacBook-Pro:docker_tests animesh$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS                   PORTS               NAMES
33f0eca77b4c        celery-image1       "/bin/bash"         2 hours ago         Up 3 seconds                                 current_image
a4607f34b309        ubuntu:latest       "/bin/bash"         4 hours ago         Exited (0) 3 hours ago                       celery_app

Animeshs-MacBook-Pro:docker_tests animesh$ docker attach current_image
root@33f0eca77b4c:/# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
none            897M  890M  7.0M 100% /
tmpfs           499M     0  499M   0% /dev
tmpfs           499M     0  499M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           897M  890M  7.0M 100% /etc/hosts
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /dev/shm

root@33f0eca77b4c:/# exit
exit

Animeshs-MacBook-Pro:docker_tests animesh$
```

I appears that I have run out of space on the VM.

I want to assign 8GB disk space and 2GB RAM to the `celery-image1` image. How can I do that?

If there are any command line parameters that I can enter when I create the container, I can do that also.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the RAM limit [according to the documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#runtime-constraints-on-resources)

The disk size it's not possible to be limited (but there is some [work on that](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/3804)).

Answer (score 0):

If you run `$man docker run` and look for "memory" you can find:

```
   -m, --memory=""
      Memory limit (format: <number>[<unit>], where unit = b, k, m or g)


   Allows you to constrain the memory available to a container. If the host supports swap memory, then the -m memory setting can be larger than physical RAM. If  a  limit
   of  0  is  specified  (not  using -m), the container's memory is not limited. The actual limit may be rounded up to a multiple of the operating system's page size (the
   value would be very large, that's millions of trillions).


   --memory-reservation=""
      Memory soft limit (format: <number>[<unit>], where unit = b, k, m or g)


   After setting memory reservation, when the system detects memory contention or low memory, containers are forced to restrict their consumption to their reservation. So
   you should always set the value below --memory, otherwise the hard limit will take precedence. By default, memory reservation will be the same as memory limit.


   --memory-swap=""
      Total memory limit (memory + swap)
```

These are the flags you can set while running the `$docker run`. It must be noticed that you can also set some limit for the CPU usage.